# Sorting all the values in a pandas matrix

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

So basically I have a pandas matrix with similarity values in it. The columns and indexes are id's of the items. So lets say we have the items A, B, C. And I would create the matrix similarity I would get something like this.

```
    A    B      C 
A  1    0.5   0.75
B  0.5   1    0.1
C  0.75  0.1   1
```

So now what I am trying to do with this matrix is somehow sort the values. I do not really care in what kind of data structure I would safe the result. But what I am trying to achieve is that by sorting this I would get something like.

```
A C 0.75
A B 0.5
C B 0.1
```

But I only found algorithems that sort the specific columns in pandas and nothing else.

Comment: Do you mean a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting upper tri by using `numpy`, then we do `stack` and `sort_values`

```
a=np.triu(df.values,-1)
a[np.tril_indices(a.shape[0], 0)] = np.nan
a
Out[414]: 
array([[  nan,  0.5 ,  0.75],
       [  nan,   nan,  0.1 ],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan]])
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=a,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)

df1.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
Out[421]: 
  level_0 level_1     0
0       A       C  0.75
1       A       B  0.50
2       B       C  0.10
```

Comment: I think you have the desired answer using np.triu. +1

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
df.stack().sort_values().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  level_0 level_1     0
0       B       C  0.10
1       C       B  0.10
2       A       B  0.50
3       B       A  0.50
4       A       C  0.75
5       C       A  0.75
6       A       A  1.00
7       B       B  1.00
8       C       C  1.00
```

Comment: I think you need to eliminate the duplicate rows and self-comparisons with something like `df = df[df.level_0 > df.level_1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Unstack would work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,.5,.75],[0.5,1,0.1],[0.75, 0.1, 1] ], index=['A','B','C'], columns =['A','B','C'])

df.unstack()


A  A    1.00
   B    0.50
   C    0.75
B  A    0.50
   B    1.00
   C    0.10
C  A    0.75
   B    0.10
   C    1.00
```